# How to add custom views to the NSSplitView divider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssplitview

What is the preferred approach to add custom views to the divider of a NSSplitView?

Taken the divider XCode uses to separate the CodeView and the Debug-OutputView, how do i add custom controls / views to the divider? Do i have to create a view and handle the drag operations myself or is it possible to customize the divider?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Xcode adds subviews to the divider bar itself, they just set them to stay attached to the top edge of their superview.